# Qualifying product:commerce_price for a product in a custom template with multiple product reference fields

Tags: commerce

My Drupal website is configured with [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), [Entity Registrations](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration), [Commerce Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_registration), and [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice).

My task is to implement registering and paying for a boatbuilding workshop that a person has the option of attending by him/herself or with a second person attending as an assistant.  The second person can attend at half price.  The workshop is limited to the number of boats being built… not the number of people attending

I first tried solving this by implementing two product variations, one for the primary attendee billed at full price, and the other for the assistant billed at half price, but found that I could not adequately control the slot limit as it based at the product variation level, and not at the product level…. e.g. the slot limit would allow double the intended slot limit, one slot set for each of the two product variations.

I then tried solving it by creating a single product to represent an attending assistant, and then adding that product reference to the content type for the workshop product.  Sort of a sub-product of a product kind-of-thing.

So the product display page has two “Add to Cart” buttons one for the workshop and one for the optional attending assistant

I found that this works and let’s me control the slot limit as desired however there is a problem. The problem is that when coding the custom template for this product and displaying the price of the workshop and the price of the optional second attendee, I don’t know how to distinguish between the two (  field product:commerce_price )

So here’s my question:

#### **Is there a way to qualify/distinguish the *product:commerce_price* field in a custom template for a product with a product reference field defined from the product variations associated with the product?
In other worlds, how do I qualify the following code snippet  to either reference the price of the product variation or the price of the product reference field in my product node?**

```
        <code><?php print render($content['product:commerce_price']); ?></code>
```

Im thinking that there must be some way to distinguish between the two because when clicking on either of the two “add to cart” buttons… the appropriate price does indeed get added.

Comment: Why not use a custom product field and a checkbox for including an assistant and then using a rule to add 50% to the price?